# How can I find the source location of console output on Windows?

Tags: windows, debugging, printf, breakpoints, visual-studio-debugging

I'm writing some software that involves Qt, GStreamer, and RTI Connext DDS. On Windows the code hangs at a certain point under certain circumstances.

Just before this happens, the message "Buffer creation failed" is printed on the console. However, this message does not occur in my code, so I assume it is generated by a dependency.

I've attached the Visual Studio debugger to the process, but because DDS is a proprietary library that was compiled in release mode, I have to compile all my code in in release mode, so it appears there is very little information you have access to. I tried to set a breakpoint on `printf` and `puts`, but this never triggers.

On Linux I'd poke around with gdb, strace, strings, and what not to try and locate the source of the message, but on Windows I have really no idea how to do these things.

Comment: Try [Time Travel Debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/time-travel-debugging-overview).